# Iphone story board not showing properly on device

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios7, xcode-storyboard

Hi i developed my application but the current storyboard is not showing properly  when i test in on the iphone.
Also the storyboard icon is shown as grey when i select it what does it means???
Here is a screenshot.
[image]

Comment: You're going to need to provide more detail for anyone to be able to answer this. What are you expecting? What's happening? What have you already tried to fix the problem? Additionally, the greyed out icon just means that the file has been modified and has yet to be saved.

Comment: Is it showing properly in the simulator but not on the device? That could mean a problem with naming the storyboard file. Keep in mind, it's case sensitive on the device. Or, it could also be a case of having to clean your project. Impossible to tell without more details.

Comment: Which kind of details do you need?

Comment: You can start by explaining what 'not showing properly' means, probably with a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted all the folder Library->Developer->Xcode->DerivedLibrary 
then cleaned the project and after that the app run perfectly in my device.